# How can I track down t.co links?

Tags: twitter, url-shortening

When you enter a URL into a tweet, Twitter uses their own in house URL shortener on the `t.co` domain to turn it into something smaller and track usage.

My site has recently been Tweeted by somebody popular (several thousand extra hits in one day) and it appears the referrer for this influx is a t.co URL.

How can I find what Tweet contained that URL?

Searching for the URL or it's parts on both Twitter and Google have turned up nothing.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7561016/198836) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3584482/198836) StackOverflow questions.

Answer (score 6):

> You should be able to find referencing Tweets by using the Search API:
>   http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=http%3A%2F%2Ft.co%2F7ADgb2YI
>
> Note that the search API will only return Tweets up to 6-9 days old, so you'll only get recent results using this approach.

(An answer by Arne Roomann-Kurrik ([@kurrik](http://twitter.com/kurrik)), Developer Advocate at Twitter, on Twitter Dev forums.)

[Source](https://twittercommunity.com/t/is-it-possible-to-trace-a-t-co-link-back-to-the-referring-tweet/7622).

Comment: This is unfortunately outdated now as the API is no longer active.